# How to store value to cache and update it once a day

Tags: magento2, cache, caching

I have got some data from an API, i like to store those data to cache and update it once a day.
I mean i don't like to call the API for each frontend page load.
I found this function

```
if (!function_exists('trustedshopscachecheck')) {
    function trustedshopscachecheck($filename_cache, $timeout = 10800) {
        if (file_exists($filename_cache) && time() - filemtime($filename_cache) < $timeout)   {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I like to use magento cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd choose a slightly different setup which will make the solution easier.

- store your value as a config value in core_config_data using `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface`
- define a job in `crontab.xml` which overwrites this value once a day
- when you want to access the value, simply access the configuration

Comment: I'd avoid storing the value in core_config_data. Those values are stored in config_cache.
Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface method getValue() reads from cache. Writing to core_config_data won't flush the cache.
Why not use Flag models. See: https://magegyver.de/using-flag-models-in-magento-2/

Comment: Very nice, didn't know this existed

Comment: The magegyver.de website didn't work for me, but this resource was helpful: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-store-variables-for-later-use/td-p/477880